# How to understand event.eventPhase?

Tags: javascript

I am confused with `event.eventPhase`. See the code below.

```js
const e1=document.getElementById("id1");
function onclicked(e)
{
  console.log(e.eventPhase);
  console.log(e);
  alert(e.target.id+' clicked');
}

e1.addEventListener('click',onclicked,false);
e1.addEventListener('click',onclicked,true);
```

```html
<div id="id1">hello world</div>
```

When clicking on "hello world", the `onclicked` function is called twice. But `console.log(e.eventPhase);` always outputs 2(AT_TARGET). More weirdly,  `console.log(e);` always shows `e.eventPhase=0`(by clicking to expand the structure e shown in Firefox devtools console). I think e.eventPhase should be 1(CAPTURING_PHASE) in the first call of onclicked and 3(BUBBLING_PHASE) in the second call, according to this [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/eventPhase).

Comment: Try putting a span inside the div and clicking that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create wrapper for your div `id="id1"` and add the same event handler on it and you will get capturing and bubbling phases on that wrapper

so when you click on the element on which you added event handler it is TARGET and it is always at target phase but capturing and bubbling goes for elements higher in the DOM tree

Answer (score 2):

You are getting Event Phase 2 when you use `event.eventPhase` and after expanding `event` it's 0, because the event is already dissolved, and `eventPhase` is none i.e. 0. And with live console, you get 0 and not 1 or 2 or 3.

---

**In a bubbling event propagation starts from the target element and passed to the parent element till the top most parent. And dissolved after that.**

```js
const phases = ['NONE', 'CAPTURING_PHASE', 'AT_TARGET', 'BUBBLING_PHASE']
const targetElement=document.getElementById("target-element");

function clickListener_1(e){
  console.log(e.currentTarget.constructor.name, phases[e.eventPhase]);
}

window.addEventListener('click', clickListener_1, false)
document.addEventListener('click', clickListener_1, false)
document.body.addEventListener('click', clickListener_1, false)
targetElement.addEventListener('click',clickListener_1, false);
```

```html
<div id="target-element">Click Here</div>
```

**whereas capture propagation starts from the top element and is passed down to the child element till the target element.**

```js
const phases = ['NONE', 'CAPTURING_PHASE', 'AT_TARGET', 'BUBBLING_PHASE']
const targetElement=document.getElementById("target-element");

function clickListener_1(e){
  console.log(e.currentTarget.constructor.name, phases[e.eventPhase]);
}

window.addEventListener('click', clickListener_1, true)
document.addEventListener('click', clickListener_1, true)
document.body.addEventListener('click', clickListener_1, true)
targetElement.addEventListener('click',clickListener_1, true);
```

```html
<div id="target-element">Click Here</div>
```

Target Element will always be at `Event.AT_TARGET` phase not `Event.CAPTURING_PHASE` or `Event.BUBBLING_PHASE`. Other elements in the propagation chain can be at `Event.CAPTURING_PHASE` or `Event.BUBBLING_PHASE` depending on propagation.

> `useCapture` passed to access propagation, Default is `false` which will be used for event bubbling propagation.  With `true` capture propagation can be accessed.

The below example may help you to understand how an event goes through different phases after the trigger. The same listener is added at both propagations, capturing, and bubbling.

```js
const phases = ['NONE', 'CAPTURING_PHASE', 'AT_TARGET', 'BUBBLING_PHASE']
const targetElement=document.getElementById("target-element");

function clickListener_1(e){
  console.log(e.currentTarget.constructor.name, phases[e.eventPhase]);
}
window.addEventListener('click', clickListener_1, true)
window.addEventListener('click', clickListener_1, false)
document.addEventListener('click', clickListener_1, true)
document.addEventListener('click', clickListener_1, false)
document.body.addEventListener('click', clickListener_1, true)
document.body.addEventListener('click', clickListener_1, false)
targetElement.addEventListener('click',clickListener_1, true);
targetElement.addEventListener('click',clickListener_1, false);
```

```html
<div id="target-element">Click Here</div>
```

[image: Event Propagation]